# Can I monitor a quarry with CraftOS?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-computercraft

I'd like to use a craftOS monitor to display whether my quarries have finished or not. How, at a basic level, would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach the gate directly next to the quarry and test for "work done"

There is a specific pullEvent you can pull to detect redstone signals:  `os.pullEvent("redstone")`